# Have Helm ternary operator return arbitrary value instead of just True / False

Tags: kubernetes-helm, conditional-operator

I've made the use of helm ternary operator and I think it's pretty need, but it seems to be only able to return boolean values. Can I have it return any arbitrary value instead of just true or false?

This works as expected

> sharedVPC: {{ true | (eq .Values.global.hyperscaler "gcp") false | quote }}

I would love to be able to do something like this

```
reclaimJobHours: {{ ternary (eq .Values.global.hyperscaler "aws") "36" "34" }}
```

Answer (score 28):

From [sprig functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html)

> The ternary function takes two values, and a test value. If the test
>   value is true, the first value will be returned. If the test value is
>   empty, the second value will be returned. This is similar to the c
>   ternary operator.

`{{ ternary "36" "34" (eq .Values.global.hyperscaler "aws")}}`

The following expression will return 36 if `global.hyperscaler` is `aws` and 34 in all other cases.